# Como puedo llamar un procedimiento almacenado con el ID auto increment?

Tags: sql

mi tabla es :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Aplicaciones(
  id int(11) auto_increment,
  cliente varchar(100),
  root varchar(300),
  dominio varchar(300),
  usuario varchar(300)
)
```

con lo cual mi procedimiento almacenado es:

```sql
use Software;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertarElemento (IN  _cli varchar(100), 
                                          _roo varchar(300),
                                          _dom varchar(300),
                                          _usr varchar(300);
insert into Aplicacaciones values(_cli, _roo, _dom, _usr)
```

con esto hago un registro pero me da error porque el ID no esta en el procedimiento
lo que necesito es que : cuando hago el registro desde el html el cliente no coloque el ID y salga automatico, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Debés especificar entre paréntesis las columnas en las que vas a hacer el `INSERT`.

Comment: No olvides además mencionar en las etiquetas qué base de datos estás utilizando (MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...) PHPMyAdmin no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. Por último, [es.so] te da las herramientas para darle formato al código/script. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Ojo tambien con el fallo tipográfico que dice **caca** en el `insert into Aplicacaciones`. Es una palabra malsonante y cuando arregles lo del ID seguramente no te funcionará por eso :-D

Answer (score 0):

No estas especificando los campos que necesitas guardar en la la base de datos, si te saltas ese paso y vas directo al values, se espera que envíes todos los datos incluyendo el id de incremento. Tu insert debe ser de la siguiente manera:

```
insert into Aplicacaciones (cliente,root,dominio,usuario) values(_cli, _roo, _dom, _usr);
```